# Models design for dynamic user choice

Tags: python, django, frontend

I want to make a clone of a website, [link](http://dyo.blksport.com), in which one can select custom design of his/her own choice. However being novice I am confused about how should I design the models for them. The app is like:

- There are items, each has a category and a sport
- There is cut for specifying the gender or age, e.g (men, junior, women) for each item.
- There is a custom graphic design which consist of several patches, where some patches can be colored
  separately from one another.
- Each item (e.g shirt), can have custom given collars and it can be half or full-sleeved
- And few others.

The front end has a feature of displaying the item in 3D, how can I achieve that?
If anyone can help me with that, then it would grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You are gonna need a 3d web graphics/rendering framework for this kinda project majorly a JavaScript library
Check this article  might help
https://bashooka.com/coding/3d-javascript-libraries/

Comment: any idea about the design of the models?